# purchases_flutter minimum deployment target error

Tags: flutter, flutter-dependencies

I am receiving the following error when I compile my FLutter project after adding package:

purchases_flutter: ^4.0.1 to it ....

[!] CocoaPods could not find compatible versions for pod "purchases_flutter":
In Podfile:
purchases_flutter (from `.symlinks/plugins/purchases_flutter/ios`)

Specs satisfying the `purchases_flutter (from` .symlinks/plugins/purchases_flutter/ios`)`
dependency were found, but they required a higher minimum deployment target.

I have checked the Readme in PubDev for this package which says:

minimum targets iOS 9.0+ is required.

However when I look in my PoDFile I have platform :ios, '10.0'. And in Xcode:

[image]

Am I missing something here. I haven't seen any other Deployment targets in Xcode or Podfile.

Would really appreciate it, if someone could point me in the correct direction with this.

Many thanks.

I have also tried creating a new Flutter project to test this from the start again and used the terminal commands as suggested below.
I still get the same error... here is a full screen shot of my Android Studio window. Showing the error, my IOS drive and Podfile.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

1. Open ios/.symlinks/plugins/your_plugin_folder/ios/your_plugin.podspec
2. Find "s.ios.deployment_target" and note its value
3. Open ios/podfile
4. At the top of this file find
   use_frameworks!
   platform :ios, '12.0'
   $iOSVersion = '12.0'
5. Replace "platform :ios" and "$iOSVersion" values with value of "s.ios.deployment_target"

Answer (score 0):

You need to prioritize your dependencies. If the problem is only with this package or plugin, just add it with `flutter pub add [dependency name]`, avoiding directly writing pubspec.yaml It prevents conflict between package versions, automatically finding appropriate version. Then in Podfile top define minimum version. Delete pubspec.lock file, ios/Podfile.lock file and ios/Pods directory. Execute `flutter pub get`. Enter ios directory via Terminal, execute `pod install` and try to run application again. If your Mac has apple silicon chip pod install command will be a bit different. Let me know, it worked or not.

Comment: Hi thanks for the response. I followed the instructions above. But when I ran the pod install I received the same error:
[!] CocoaPods could not find compatible versions for pod "purchases_flutter":
  In Podfile:
    purchases_flutter (from `.symlinks/plugins/purchases_flutter/ios`)

Specs satisfying the `purchases_flutter (from `.symlinks/plugins/purchases_flutter/ios`)` dependency were found, but they required a higher minimum deployment target.

Comment: In Podfile, did you show iOS version? And didn’t you skip any step?

Comment: Could you share screenshots please for each step and error message

Comment: # Uncomment this line to define a global platform for your project
platform :ios, '10.0'

Comment: Above find the definition in my PodFile. Yes I followed the steps. Btw I also created a  new Flutter project and followed this there. Still doesn't work. Same error.

Comment: please see above, I added a screen shot also. Thanks for any help.

Comment: Yea I saw. Let’s make iOS version 13. And then again try the steps starting deleting pods dir podfile lock pubspec lock files, then re execute flutter pub get and pod install inside ios folder. It should work

Answer (score 0):

What worked for me was to set the below on the podfile

```
# Uncomment this line to define a global platform for your project
platform :ios, '11.0'
```